# SQL Left Outer Join On Clause Placement

Tags: sql

I was informed today that the ON clause for a Left Outer Join actually determines which table is the left vs right. As I look at this, I do not actually see any differences in results if I move the key from the left or right in the ON clause. I have also looked around on technet but I am unable to find any documentation regarding this.

Does the placement of keys in the ON clause actually determine which table is to the left or right, and would it cause different resultsets?

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.ProductKey = r.ProductKey


SELECT *
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON r.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
```

Comment: no.but it can be a performance factor for some DBMS.

Comment: @Sanka: there is no modern DBMS where that would make a difference

Comment: You are informed wrong.  Your two queries are equivalent -- ANSI standard, so the result sets are the same.  It is hard to imagine a SQL compiler that *could* produce different plans for the two queries..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the table you list in the `FROM` clause is the "left side" of the query, and any table(s) you list in the `JOIN` clause(s) are "right side".

```
SELECT ...
FROM lefttable
JOIN righttable ON ...
```

and then the left/right join keyword determines WHICH of those two tables is used:

all "left" records with ANY available "right" records:

```
SELECT
FROM lefttable
LEFT JOIN righttable ON ...
```

all "right" records with ANY available "left" records:

```
SELECT ...
FROM lefttable
RIGHT JOIN righttable ON ...
```

Swapping the right/left semantics makes for essentially the same query:

```
SELECT ... FROM lefttable  RIGHT JOIN righttable ON ...
SELECT ... FROM righttable LEFT JOIN  lefttable ON ...
```